# Get the complete data of a visual in powerbi from an embedded report and export to CSV/excel

Tags: excel, csv, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-api

I have a powerbi report embedded in a react app. In the page I have a table visual from which I want to export the complete data in form of CSV/Excel.

This is the way I am currently using:

```
const pages = await report.getPages();
let page = pages.filter(function (page) {
  return page.isActive;
})[0];
const visuals = await page.getVisuals();
for (let index = 0; index < visuals.length; index++) {
  if (visuals[index].title === "Extra Col") {
    let result = await visuals[index].exportData(
      models.ExportDataType.Summarized
    );
    console.log("result data", result);
```

After getting the result I am converting the data like this:

```
const csvArray = result.data.split("\r\n").map((row) => row.split(","));
```

and then passing the csvArray data to react-csv to download as csv.

In this way I am only getting the data of first 1500 to 1600 rows. I want to know is there any way to get the complete data or directly export the data in form of CSV/Excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `models.ExportDataType.Summarized` will export data what you see currently in the visual.

Use `models.ExportDataType.Underlying` and it will export data what you see in the visual plus additional data from the underlying dataset.

Refer [Export Data from a visual](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/export-data#how-to-export-a-visuals-data) for more information.

The maximum number of rows you can export is 30,000. Check [Considerations and limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/export-data#considerations-and-limitations).